# spring-amqp how to reuse an existing exchange and not create a new one

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a question that I was not able to figure out. Say an exchange xyz is set up for rabbitmq. My spring application will start up fine and use the application correctly. The problem is that the client does not want us to create an Exchange from the spring application if the exchange does not exist. Is there a way to set the exchange to not auto create when our application starts from our rabbitmqConfiguration class.

Answer (score 2):

Set `auto-declare="false"` on the exchange (or omit it completely from your configuration).

Comment: I should have added that I am using annotation setup with @Configuration so i do not have the XML config setup available. I was not able to find hte auto-declare flag for the exchange information.

Comment: setShouldDeclare an the @Bean. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/core/AbstractDeclarable.html#setShouldDeclare-boolean-